# static linking libtiff to qt

Tags: qt, libtiff

I'm trying to create a static application in qt so that I can run it on other platforms. I made qt static and compiled an example using these commands:

```
make clean
qmake -config release
make
```

and it runs ok on my system (ubuntu 13.10) but when I move the executable file to another system (ubuntu 12.04 lts) it gives me this error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libtiff.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I can find the file libtiff.so.4 on that system but not libtiff.so.5 and of course I don't really want to install anything cause I wan my app to have as few dependencies as possible. How can I link libtiff to my app properly?

Comment: Did you figure it out? Same question